# Measure real world distance between objects in an image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have an image containing some number of circles. I'd like to select two of them and calculate the real world distance between them. I would like to make precise measurements so I need to account for camera pose and lens distortion.
I have calibrated my camera using OpenCV's calibrateCamera so I have the projection from the real world to the sensor, I have the camera intrinsics and extrinsics and distortion coefficients.
I know the accurate pixel coordinates of the circles, how do I convert them to real world coordinates while accounting for camera pose and distortion?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of tutorials online about this. Have you googled your question?

Comment: Yes, very helpful, but I've googled the question. Generally these tutorials are oversimplified. 'Calibrating' the camera by looking at an object of known size and then getting a simple px/mm conversion and assuming no distortion, not using the camera pose.

Comment: How about this one from the OpenCV docs? https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html — Your question right now asks to write quite a long tutorial. You have a much better chance of getting a useful answer if you show what your current level of understanding is, what bits of the process you figured out, and where the gaps are. Filling in gaps in understanding is much, much easier than writing the whole tutorial.

Comment: Ok I understand  your point. I have gone through all of the camera calibration tutorials and have implemented calibration myself, I have acceptable reprojection errors, can undistort, etc. But my question is in how to use this information to get accurate real world measurements. I've watched some videos that describe inverting the projection matrices, so going back from 2D to 3D but was wondering what others have done here. But you're right. I've asked too general of a question. Perhaps I will remove and repost a better one.

Comment: Once you’ve obtained a rectified version of the checkerboard pattern, you should have equally-sized squares all across your image. You should know the physical size of these squares, and you can manually measure their size in the image. This gives you a mm/pixel value or whatever. For any new image, rectify, and you now know how to translate pixels to physical sizes *for flat objects in the plane of the calibration checkerboard*. Objects out of plane, or after the camera moved, cannot be measured.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you. I notice that e.g. the OpenCV undistort function takes the camera intrinsic matrix and distortion parameters but not the extrinsic parameters, i.e. the pose of the camera. I'll have to think about that. If the camera were say rotated around the z axis by 2 degrees and I try to measure the distance between two points I could get cosine errors.  Thanks

Comment: If the circles are all on a plane and you know the real-world size of the circles you can use a homography for 2D image to 2D plane transformation, where 2D plane is in real world units.